# How do I redirect to domain name without the trailing /

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Currently, if I go to my site...

`example.com   OR   example.com/index.php`

...I am redirected to...

`example.com/`

However, I would like to stop the addition of the training / when visiting the main page.

The following is my htaccess file...

```
IndexIgnore *

ErrorDocument 400 /error
ErrorDocument 401 /error
ErrorDocument 403 /error
ErrorDocument 404 /error
ErrorDocument 500 /error

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(home|cv|handouts|links|contact|copyright|cv)/?$ /index.php?module=home&action=$1
RewriteRule ^(log(in|out))/?$ /index.php?module=authentication&action=$1

RewriteRule ^photos/?$ /index.php?module=gallery&action=album&album=general
RewriteRule ^gallery/?$ /index.php?module=gallery&action=album&album=general
RewriteRule ^gallery/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?module=gallery&action=album&album=$1
RewriteRule ^gallery/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?module=gallery&action=album&album=$1$&page=$2
RewriteRule ^gallery/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?module=gallery&action=item&album=$1$&page=$2&item=$3

RewriteRule ^release/?$ /index.php?module=release&action=release
RewriteRule ^error/?$ /index.php?module=error&action=error
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just wondering, what's wrong with the `/` ? What would be of `GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\n\r\n` without the slash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do what you want.

The trailing slash in `http://example.com/` is not part of the path but should rather be considered a delimiter just like the slashes in the beginning of the URL. If I enter a URL in my browser without a trailing slash the browser will actually append it to the host name before submitting a GET request for the URL. No redirection is taking place.